# Fast split rows of a specific column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Probes':["1415693_at","1415693_at"],
                   'Genes':["Canx","LOC101056688 /// Wars "],
                   'cv_filter':[ 0.134,0.290],
                   'Organ' :["LN","LV"]}   )    
df = df[["Probes","Genes","cv_filter","Organ"]]
```

It looks like this:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
       Probes                   Genes  cv_filter Organ
0  1415693_at                    Canx      0.134    LN
1  1415693_at  LOC101056688 /// Wars       0.290    LV
```

What I want to do is to split rows based on Genes column where it entries 
is delimited by '///'.

The result I'd like to get is

```
       Probes                   Genes  cv_filter Organ
0  1415693_at                    Canx      0.134    LN
1  1415693_at            LOC101056688      0.290    LV
2  1415693_at                    Wars      0.290    LV
```

In total I have ~150K rows to check. Is there a fast method to process that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try first [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) column `Genes`, create new `Series` and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) it to original `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Probes':["1415693_at","1415693_at"],
                   'Genes':["Canx","LOC101056688 /// Wars "],
                   'cv_filter':[ 0.134,0.290],
                   'Organ' :["LN","LV"]}   )    
df = df[["Probes","Genes","cv_filter","Organ"]]  
print df
       Probes                   Genes  cv_filter Organ
0  1415693_at                    Canx      0.134    LN
1  1415693_at  LOC101056688 /// Wars       0.290    LV

s = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('///') for x in df['Genes'].tolist() ], index=df.index).stack()
#or you can use approach from comment
#s = df['Genes'].str.split('///', expand=True).stack()

s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1) 
s.name = 'Genes' 
print s
0             Canx
1    LOC101056688 
1            Wars 
Name: Genes, dtype: object

#remove original columns, because error:
#ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index([u'Genes'], dtype='object')    
df = df.drop('Genes', axis=1)

df = df.join(s).reset_index(drop=True)
print df[["Probes","Genes","cv_filter","Organ"]] 
       Probes          Genes  cv_filter Organ
0  1415693_at           Canx      0.134    LN
1  1415693_at  LOC101056688       0.290    LV
2  1415693_at          Wars       0.290    LV
```

Comment: Why not `df['Genes'].str.split('///', expand=True).stack()` instead of `df['Genes'].str.split('///').apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()`. It's about 2x times faster

Comment: @AntonProtopopov - Thank you. I add it to my answer as alternative solution (just a little bit slower as `DataFrame` constructor).

Comment: You are right, so `index` is added to `DataFrame` constructor.